# How to make buttons grow/shrink in response to the cursor hovering over it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some simple styled buttons on my project page for my web dev class, and I wanted to know if it was possible to make it so that the buttons react when the user's mouse hovers over them. Growing when hovered over and shrinking when the mouse moves away. I'm fairly new to web development, so I wasn't sure if this was somethin doable in HTML/CSS, or if it would require some javascript tinkering.

Comment: Sure is. Take a look at the hover selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: Hi Anoel, and welcome to StackOverflow! Next time please try to come up with code you've tried before :)

Answer (score 0):

There's `:hover` selector in CSS that can help you achieve that. If your button has some class, e.g. "sendForm", you can do something like:

```
.sendForm {
    width: 2rem; //or other units
}
.sendForm:hover {
    width: 4rem; // or other units
}
```

However, I'd recommend to change size of padding on button  so that the text always fits inside, like:

```
.sendForm {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px; 
}
.sendForm:hover {
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px; 
}
```

you can also use shorthand notation: `padding: 0 8px`; Please refer to MDn if you want to learn more about padding notation in CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Answer (score 0):

pretty straightforward.  just use css and hover on the button

```css
button:hover{

width:120px;
height:60px;
display:inline-block;
font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```